# api navigates without being clicked on

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, use-effect

I have an api call, after the api call control navigates to other screen. The problem is, the method executes itself even before the user has a chance to invoke the method. I want the user to give input and then call api to validate if the input is correct and then to navigate to another screen.

This is my api code

```
const PinCode = dispatch => async ({vCode}) => {
console.log('entro');
try {
    const vSolicitudeId = await AsyncStorage.getItem('SolicitudeId');
    const response = await ForceApi.post('/ValidateCodeController.php', {vSolicitudeId,vCode});
    dispatch({ type: 'guardar', payload: response.data.id});
    console.log(response.data.message);
    console.log(response.data.code);
    navigate('Calculadora',);
} catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
    dispatch({
    type: 'add_error',
    payload: 'Error de Conexion'
    });
}
```

};

and this is how it is called

```
const {state, PinCode} = useContext(Context);
  const [vCode, setvCode] = useState('');

  useEffect(() => { 
    PinCode({vCode});
  }, []);
return (
  <View style={styles.container}>
    <View>
      <Text style={styles.textIniciar}>Verificación de PIN</Text>
    </View>
    <View>
      <Text style={styles.Pin}>Ingresa el código que hemos enviado al número registrado.</Text>
    </View>
      <View style={styles.inputContainer}>
          <TextInput style={styles.inputs}
            placeholder="Código"
            underlineColorAndroid='transparent'
            onChangeText={newvCode => setvCode(newvCode)}
            value={vCode}
            autoCorrect={false}
            autoCapitalize='characters'
          />
      </View>
      <TouchableOpacity style={[styles.buttonContainer, styles.loginButton]}  
        onPress={() => PinCode({vCode})}>
        <Text style={styles.loginText}>ENVIAR</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
      <View>
      <Text style={styles.Pin}>¿No se ha recibido el código de verificación?</Text>
      <Text style={styles.Pin}>Reenviar</Text>
      </View>
  </View>
);
```

};

any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The root of your problem is in this code snippet

```
  useEffect(() => { 
    PinCode({vCode});
  }, []);
```

Hook useEffect can be called when depended data will be changed.
But if you will pass '[]' as a second argument, the code inside will be performed only once, when the component will be mounted. And that is what happens in your case.
More info https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html

As I see from your code, you can just remove this useEffect and all should work fine, as you want.

Comment: no, i removed the use effect and leaved PinCode({vCode}); but it stills navigate without the user doing anything

Comment: fix it, this way

{useEffect(() => {
    if (vCode) {
      PinCode({vCode});
    }
  }, [vCode]);

Comment: If you want to send new vCode automatically after the user will update it, it's a good solution. But here could a problem that while user will type a new value, you will send all intermediate values. 
If you need to send data only after user will click a button, you shouldn't use hook useEffect.